# Blender Texrures streaching

Tags: texturing

I downloaded a texture and put it on my anvil. As expected, the texture stretched out acrost the whole anvil and looked ugly. Is there a way to repeat the texture on every vertex face or repeat a few times over the whole anvil?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe learning a bit of Uv unwrapping can help

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cS6B5PAzlWI